# Images Not Displayed to Members

Tags: ee2

So, this seems really weird. For some reason, images are not displaying for logged in users (exception are Superusers). The website is 3 years old and I know images were showing regardless of whether a visitor was logged in or not so, this seems to be a recent issue although I don't know when this started.

After trying to disable all 3rd-party plugins and building a test template with no javascript or CSS rules, the issue still exists.

After more experimentation, I can now display images to logged in users IF I allow a member group permission to upload images in the Control Panel. None of our members groups have Control Panel access nor should they so this is not a good, permanent solution.

Any thoughts on what I should check here to fix this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't remember the number of the bug report, but I believe this is an old and fixed bug. Which version are you using?

Comment: Thanks for your input...I should have searched EE's bug tracker first although when I did search, nothing came up. Anyway, we're kind of stuck on 2.5.3 because of a custom plugin but I think it's time to bite the bullet and upgrade.